# PySpark create nested structure during transformation

Tags: pyspark

Using PySpark, I have a dataframe with a schema similar to the following:

```
root
 |-- id: string
 |-- v1: string
 |-- v2: string
 |-- v3: string
```

I now want to select and transform the data into something like:

```
root
 |-- ident: string
 |-- custom: struct
 |    |-- val1: string
 |    |-- val2: string
 |    |-- val3: string
```

I thought this would work:

```
df = (df.withColumn('ident', df['id'])
        .withColumn('custom.val1', df['v1'])
        .withColumn('custom.val2', df['v2'])
        .withColumn('custom.val3', df['v3'])
        .select(['ident', 'custom'])
```

However, as you can gather, it doesn't.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`struct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.struct.html#pyspark.sql.functions.struct) to create a struct column:

```
df.selectExpr('id', 'struct(v1, v2, v3) as custom').printSchema()

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- custom: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- v1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- v2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- v3: string (nullable = true)
```

Or use select:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.select('id', f.struct(df.v1, df.v2, df.v3).alias('custom')).show()

+---+---------+
| id|   custom|
+---+---------+
|  a|[b, c, d]|
+---+---------+
```

Data:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']], ['id', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3'])
```

Comment: Works as advertised, only change I made was to add ".alias('val1,2,3')" to each of the subfields.  Simple and straightforward.  Thank you.

Comment: Ahh you're right, didn't notice you renamed the subfield.